# Which Web-Mapping Tool to use to create Interactive Web-Gis

Tags: javascript, maps, gis, geodjango, geoext

i am planning to create a web-gis application. Different raster and vector data will be displayed on a basemap (which will be stored in geoserver / postgis). The user will be able to define a time interval / scenario etc. (so query options will be needed) and the map will change accordingly. Also some graphs (statistics and infographics) should be included and for example pop up when clicking a feature on the map.

I did some research and there are of course multiple possibilities and techniques to create such web-gis.
I already now some and came across openlayers, geoext but also python based geodjango.

My problem is that i can't quite decide which tool to use to start programming the application. Is a relatively large framework like geoext or django necessary, or should i just start with some plain javascript and openlayers? Does anyone have some experience in web-mapping and can recommend me a tool or just an approach to the topic as i am a little bit lost in the possibilities and techniques to create the application.

I got experience in javascript and python, although its self-learned and i wouldn't consider my skills professional yet.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I am also having same problem, but using `geoext` and `openlayers`, solved for me. They fit well for such type of projects.